# Updating BIOS from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dell, bios

I am using DELL Latitude 3400 laptop. How is it possible to update the BIOS from Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: "How is it possible to update the BIOS from Ubuntu 20.04." because Dell has excellent support for Linux. See for instance  https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment

Comment: On my Dell Latitude 5510 I lowered the security level and turned off secure boot. The command to use is "fwupdmgr update". Worked for me.

Comment: @karel Thanks. It worked. Please upvote the question